# Web Part Feature

Tags: web-part, feature

I'm working on a (non-visual) Web Part and wish to read from an xml file placed in the "`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\wpresources`" folder:

Code-Behind:

```
string sUri = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80" + @"\wpresources\links.xml";
```

Can someone help me with the correct syntax for the Feature.xml to include this XML file when deploying the Feature?

**UPDATE 10-08-2012:**

Tried adding links.xml to same location as the Web Part and got following error:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot find this file specified in the manifest file: SecureLinksWP_Feature1\SecureLinks\links.xml

**Elements.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="SecureLinks" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="SecureLinks\SecureLinks.webpart" Url="SecureLinks.webpart"
      Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
    <File Path="SecureLinks\links.xml" Url="SecureLinks/links.xml"
      Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

**Feature1.Template.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature Id="4BB4B62C-4F2F-4BB5-A477-DF783B802DD5" 
         Title="SecureLinksWP"
         Scope="Site"
         Version="1.0.0.0"
         Hidden="FALSE"
         DefaultResourceFile="core"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="SecureLinks\Elements.xml" />
        <ElementFile Location="SecureLinks\SecureLinks.webpart" />
        <ElementFile Location="SecureLinks\links.xml" />
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Comment: why don't add this file to your feature code and deploy it as a solution if its only going to be used by feature ?

Comment: Could you give me the syntax for that in an answer, URL, PATH, etc? I had difficulty configuring it like this...

Comment: @yaron, updating question

Comment: code you entered is for "element.xml" not feature.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try WSP builder to develop a solution file and include this xml file within your solution but that will be case only if this file is there to be used by this feature only.

you can download and install it from link below, and its a Visual studio extension

http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

hope it helps :)

Edit

Copy that file to your feature folder and add this line to your code

```
<ElementManifest Location="links.xml" />
```

so it will be something like this

```
<Feature 
Title="Title" 
Description="sssss" 
Id="ID" 
Scope="Site" 
Version="1.0.0.0" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="links.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

**EDIT 2**

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="SecureLinks" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="SecureLinks\SecureLinks.webpart" Url="SecureLinks.webpart"
      Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
    <File Path="SecureLinks\links.xml" Url="links.xml"
      Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
//not sure why you don't have property name here ?
      </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Maybe I should put the links.xml file in its own module because the module URL is different for the Web Part?

Comment: I think you should match your code with one in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586611(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: They are defining path in Module tag and then just providing URL to file, I would help you more but I have to go now, hope your problem get solved :)

Comment: Still getting the error above...

Comment: tell me what this feature is actually doing and whats the part of links.xml in it

Comment: It's a set of links to internal apps with role and auth attributes for each app. This Feature contains the code logic and file of links - it displays the link if the logged-in user has sufficient permissions.

Comment: "it displays the link if the logged-in user has sufficient permissions." can't that happen using a webpart ? like if you create a webpart that is hidden by default and on page load method check if user have enough permissions then display webpart otherwise keep it hidden, am just trying to think about an easy way of doing this task to be honest.

Comment: I already have this implemented in SP2007 but was using 3rd party tools for the project. Now I need to use only VS2010 and the only thing giving me probs is configuring the XML files :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6016/discussion-between-yaron-and-irishchieftain)